# PHP How can i get a string between a specific string and the previous newline

Tags: php, string

Ok for the last few days i've been trying to work this out. I have the task of parsing a string of text that i have no control over how its generated therefor it has caused me a couple issues.

I have figured out how to grab all the information from this string and echo it except for the Branding line

```
$string = "
 Coat: Black
 Heart Branding
 Looney Leg Heart";

function GetBetween($var1="",$var2="",$pool){
$temp1 = strpos($pool,$var1)+strlen($var1);
$result = substr($pool,$temp1,strlen($pool));
$dd=strpos($result,$var2);
if($dd == 0){
    $dd = strlen($result);
}

return substr($result,0,$dd);
}

//Hair Gloom
if (preg_match('/Hair Gloom /',$string)){
echo GetBetween("Hair Gloom ","\n",$string);
}else{
    echo "N/A";
}

//Branding
if (preg_match('/ Branding/',$string)){
    echo GetBetween("\n","Branding ",$string);
}else{
    echo "N/A";
}

//Hoof
if (preg_match('/Hoof/',$string)){
    echo GetBetween("Hoof","\n",$string);
 }else{
    echo "N/A";
}

//Looney Leg
if (preg_match('/Looney Leg /',$string)){
    echo GetBetween("Looney Leg ","\n",$string);
}else{
    echo "N/A";
}
```

Because the information i need to gather for the branding is behind it in the string i cant seem to grab it, the way it is there it just prints from the first new line in the string to the word Branding.

I thought of maybe turning it into an array and finding the line number that has the word branding but that ended up returning null.

At this point im just annoying with how these strings are assembled as it makes everything have to be more dynamic and cant have fixed values for the most part.

The output should be something like this

```
N/A Heart N/A Heart
```

But what it does is this

```
N/A Coat: Black Heart Branding N/A Heart
```

I've been learning PHP only for the last month now so im not well versed in it quite yet so any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to be about only 2 or three strings and provide which output you get, and which output you want instead.

Comment: show expected result from the examlpe string

Comment: Ok i edited the post to include actual response and expected response and removed some of the strings to simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first make an associative array that has the names you want to look for as keys, and already assign the default "N/A" value to them all:

```php
$items = [
    "Hair Gloom" => "N/A", 
    "Branding" => "N/A", 
    "Hoof" => "N/A", 
    "Looney Leg" => "N/A"
];
```

Then you could create a regular expression based on those keys. You would make the colon optional (as it only appears after some of those keys), and grab any content that precedes or follows it on the same line. The `.` will not match newlines, so that will guarantee (together with using `\h` for white space) that matches will not span multiple lines:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*)\b(" . implode("|", array_keys($items)) . ")\b:?\h*(.*)/",
            $string,
            $matches);
```

After this, `$matches` will have at:

- index 0 all complete matches (which do not interest us)
- index 1 the part that matched with the left most `(.*)` which will be useful for the "Branding" case
- index 2 the key itself, which we will use to change the corresponding entry in `$items`
- index 3 the part that matched with the right most `(.*)` which will be useful for the normal (non-"Branding") cases

So here is how we can process that information:

```
foreach ($matches[2] as $i => $key) {
    $items[$key] = trim($matches[1][$i] . $matches[3][$i]); 
}
```

Now `$items` will have had two updated values:

```
[
    "Hair Gloom" => "N/A",
    "Branding" => "Heart",
    "Hoof" => "N/A",
    "Looney Leg" => "Heart"
]
```

To only get the values use:

```
array_values($items)
```

which will be

```
["N/A", "Heart", "N/A", "Heart"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Preg match all:

```
$input_lines="Zero Word
One Foo
Two Word
Three Bar
";

preg_match_all("/([\r\n]|^)([ a-zA-Z0-9]*)Word/", $input_lines, $output_array);

print_r($output_array);
```

Result is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zero Word
            [1] => 
Two Word
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zero 
            [1] => Two 
        )

)
```

Where [2] element is your answer

Words "Zero" and "Two" are between specific word "Word" and previous newline/start of the file.